# I have created a list using find_all in Beautiful soup based on an attribute. How do I return he node I want?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I have a MS word document template that has Structured documents tags, including repeating sections. I am using a Python script to pull the important parts and and send them to a dataframe. My script works as intended on 80% of the documents I have attempted but I am often failing. The issue is when finding the first repeating section I have been doing the following:

```py
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
    soup = BS(f, 'xml')  # entire xml; file is called soup
    soupdocument=soup.document  #document only child node of soup  
    soupbody=soupdocument.body  # body is the only child node of document 
    ODR=soupbody.contents[5]
```

which often works however some users have managed to hit enter in some places in the document that are not locked down. I know the issue should be resolved by not choosing the 5th element of soupbody.

```py
    soupbody.find_all({tag})
><w:tag w:val="First Name"/>,
 <w:tag w:val="Last Name"/>,
 <w:tag w:val="Position"/>,
 <w:tag w:val="Phone Number"/>,
 <w:tag w:val="Email"/>,
 <w:tag w:val="ODR Repeating Section"/>,
```

the above is a partial list of what is returned the actual list several dozen tags and some are repeated. the section I want is the last one I listed above and is usually but not always found by the first code block. I believe I can put a colon after find_all({tag:SOMETHING}} I have tried cutting and pasting all different parts of "ODR Repeating Section" but It doesn't work. What is the correct way to find this section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi perhaps specify the attribute you're searching for in addition to the tag name?

```
tags = soup.findAll('tag', {'val" : 'ODR Repeating Section'})
```

Comment: Perhaps try `w:val` or `w:tag`?

Comment: `w:val` works without `w:tag` Thank you, I had been stuck for a while.